# Почему не запускается telegram бот?

Tags: python, aiogram, cmd, pycharm

Написал бота на python. IDE использовал PyCharm и с ним все запускается хорошо, но при попытке запустить бота через консоль выпадает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все файлы находятся в одной папке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Как именно вы запускаете через консоль*

Comment: запускал через команду `py main.py`